# Gridview Header Styling

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview, header

For quite some time I've been struggling to restyle the Gridview headers. I would like to obtain the look of a simple grid with borders around the header. 
By changing the HeaderContainerStyle and the HeaderTemplate I end up with a texbox and a border inside the actual headers like this:

[image: Headers]

I would like to end up with something like this:

[image: Headers]

This is what I have tried so far:

```
<GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border BorderThickness="1 1 0 1" BorderBrush="Black" >
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </DockPanel>
         </Border>
     </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
```

What do I have to change to get the desired results?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the look of the column header by defining your own custom DataGridColumnHeader style. Please refer to the following sample markup. It should give you the idea.

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderGripperStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="8"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeWE"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header..." Binding="{Binding}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                    </Border>
                                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}"/>
                                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Maroon" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontWeight" Value="SemiBold" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Your example used with GridViewColumnHeader did the job! Thank you for your help!